# Inclusion of separate files in a main file show error for graphics

Tags: graphics, include, includegraphics, compilation-error

When I call two separate files(chapters) from a main file, it shows error for `graphicx`.   Details are bellows:

(i)   The main file `main.tex` contains following contents:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\author{No Author}
\title{Simple Book Example}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\include{ch1/chapter01}
\include{ch2/chapter02}
\backmatter
\end{document}
```

(ii) The first chapter `chapter01.tex` contained in the directory `ch1`. The `chapter01.tex` contains the following contents:

```
\chapter{first chapter}
Text sample
\includegraphics{konigsberg1}
```

The image `konigsberg1.png` contained in `ch1`.

Similarly, the second chapter `chapter02.tex` contained in the directory `ch2`. The `chapter02.tex` contains the following contents:

```
\chapter{second  chapter}
Text sample for 2nd ch
\includegraphics{Jordan_curve}
```

The image `Jordan_curve` contained in `ch2`.

These two directories `ch1` and `ch2` are contained in the directory where the main file contained.

When I compile with `pdflatex` in texstudion on MacOS, it shows that

> File `konigsberg1' not found.

for line `\includegraphics{konigsberg1}` and

> File `Jordan_curve' not found.

for `\includegraphics{Jordan_curve}`. But when I comment out `includegraphics`, then everything is ok.

How can I fix error?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
\graphicspath{{ch1}{ch2}}
```

to your preamble